# Android: installing apk on emulator while running openGL ES2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have enabled the GPU Support on my Emulator.

but i received the error

Installing Testing.apk...
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1911 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1380 error 0x501
 sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetAttribLocation:825 error 0x501
 sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1911 error 0x501

And so on....

PLz help me.. Very grateful to you.

Comment: Look at this question@ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415111/opengl-with-vbo-gives-error-0x501

Answer (score 0):

According to this question: [opengl with vbo gives error 0x501](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415111/opengl-with-vbo-gives-error-0x501)

the error is when

> As per the docs: "GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if offset or size is
>   negative, or if together they define a region of memory that extends
>   beyond the buffer object's allocated data store."

Comment: @SheikhFaisal I can't help you if you refuse to post your code.